# From vertical to horizontal output in python?

Tags: python, list

I'm trying to create two lists of random dna sequences, dna1 and dna2.
My code below is returning the random sequences of dna1 and dna2 in vertical order. I wonder how could I create a list for each dna result in horizontal format.

```
import numpy as np 
BASES = ('A','C','T','G')

def random_dna_sequence(length):
    return ''.join(np.random.choice(BASES,length)) #list() can be used 

with open('dna.txt', 'w+') as txtout:
    for _ in range(3):
        dna1 = random_dna_sequence(2)
        dna2 = random_dna_sequence(2)
        txtout.write(dna1)
        txtout.write(dna2)
        txtout.write("")
        print(dna1)
        print(dna2)
```

Output:

```
 CT
 AC
 AC

 AT
 AG
 CC
```

Expected outcome:

```
 dna1 = ['CT','AC','AC']
 dna2 = ['AT','AG','CC']
```

Comment: Thanks jakub! Do you know how could I obtain a list of results like the one expected? I'm a little bit trapped here, I don't know how to fix it

Comment: @jakub `file.write` doesn't write a newline

Comment: @MartaFredes Your question is slightly unclear. Your code currently prints values to a file like so: `AAGCGAACAGTT`. This is because you don't add any spaces (you joined on `''` and also do `txtout.write("")` (which does absolutely nothing, btw). Do you want the expected output to be in the file or on the console? Writing to a file is not the same as printing to the console.

Comment: Why would you expect your output to look like that? Nothing in your code even attempts to create the string `'dna1 = [...'` etc.

Comment: Thank you all for your comments! I'm quite new with Python and I was trying to see if there was a way to obtain the requested output. I appreciate your help!

Comment: From your reaction on answers, I suggest to reduce your [example] to _only one `dna` variable` printed_ and to __move _file-output_ part__ to a separate question/post 

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you have to use the file?
If you need lists, then the code will be like this.

```
import numpy as np 
BASES = ('A','C','T','G')

def random_dna_sequence(length):
    return ''.join(np.random.choice(BASES,length)) #list() can be used 

dna1 = [random_dna_sequence(2) for _ in range(3)]
dna2 = [random_dna_sequence(2) for _ in range(3)]

print(dna1)
print(dna2)
```

Returned values:

```
['AG', 'CG', 'AG']
['TA', 'TC', 'AA']
```

Comment: No, I don't need to use the file actually. Thank you so much for this. It's a great solution :)

Comment: @MartaFredes I can see you are a new contributor. If this solution solves your question, please remember to upvote it and accept it as an answer. That is usually the best way of saying "thank you" and motivates users to keep helping people.

Comment: This answer is solving by introducing 2 concepts: (1) __list__ as printable data structure (key in solving), (2) creating lists from _iteration_ by __list-comprehension__ (**advanced** _language construct_ in Python). Both require explanation to beginners asking. Just dumping code is solving but might be less helpful 

Answer (score 2):

[Александр Рахмаев answered](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66818281/5730279) with a working solution.

Just want to highlight your issue here.

### Already working: from array to pairs

Seems in your domain (Genetics) you are combining **bases** (single letters from a specific set of 4) to pairs (string of 2 letters).

Therefore you use *numpy*'s function to randomize the combination: `np.random.choice(BASES, 2)`. It will return an array, try `print( np.random.choice(BASES, 2) )`, looks similar to:

> array(['A', 'T']) # 1 dimensional array with 2 random elements

Now you need to combine these 2 elements to a pair, `join`ed with empty-string `''`, which means concatenated to a String.
So `print( ''.join(np.random.choice(BASES,2)) )` will print

> AT

You can now add many of these random pairs to a list.
Your code did so using a for-loop with 3 iterations:

```py
for _ in range(3):  # for each of the 3 iterations do:
    print( random_dna_sequence(2) )  # print each random base-pair
```

In fact the output is 3 separate lines.

The other answer did same 3 iterations shorter, inside the brackets (`[]`, *list-comprehension*): `random_dna_sequence(2) for _ in range(3)`

### Issue: add each pair to a *list* (data structure)

Then you can print the finally filled list after the 3rd element has been added. Python's print-function will then automatically format the list as you expected, almost:

> ['AG', 'CG', 'AG']

#### List comprehension (pythonic)

What the other answer accomplished with *list-comprehension* inside the brackets:

```py
# add 3 random pairs to a list, named variable: dna
dna = [random_dna_sequence(2) for _ in range(3)]
```

- create a list `dna` and add all 3 elements from iteration inside brackets
- the right-hand side of the assigning `=` is called **list-comprehension**

#### For loop (generic)

Same can be done by your for-loop. All you need to change is:

- define `dna` as an empty list before the loop
- add the pair to the list, inside your loop (for each of the 3 iterations): `dna.add( pair )`
- print the list named `dna` after the loop (code formatted without indentation)

#### Difficulty for beginners

I found a similar question: [New to learning python; why is the print for this for-loop different when I use a list comprehension? how do i make the loop be the same?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66835187/5730279). This might shed light on some difficulties.

### Solution: adding pairs to a list

The file-writing is omitted!

```py
dna1 = []  # define empty list
dna2 = []

for _ in range(3):
    dna1.append( random_dna_sequence(2) )  # add pair to list
    dna2.append( random_dna_sequence(2) )

print(dna1)  # print list containing 3 elements (3 pairs)
print(dna2)
```

Now, to add something in front, simply add inside the print-function - separated by comma: `print('dna2 =', dna2)` will output as expected

> dna1 = ['AG', 'CG', 'AG']

For the file-output the question remains:

- How do you expect the contents (here: the pairs) to be written?

  - A pair per line
  - All pairs in one line, maybe separated by comma or enclosed in quotes.

Comment: This is very helpful, thank you so much for this great explanation!

Comment: @MartaFredes  Rewarding to me that my explanation helped your understanding of basic __programming concepts__: lists, loops, output. It's about organizing data to your needs (data structures, loop) and then (separation-of-concerns) at the end presenting it (print or file-write) 