# New to learning python; why is the print for this for-loop different when I use a list comprehension? how do i make the loop be the same?

Tags: python, for-loop, list-comprehension

from my understanding shouldn't the print for X be the same on both? the answer i need is the one that comes from the list-comprehension, which is a new list where every element is -1 from the original list. But the for-loop one only gives 1 element, I also don't know how that element is calculated. Printing x just gives the last element of the list. I'm sure i'm doing something wrong but i'm not sure how to get a list from just using the for-loop. WHAT IS CONFUSING ME is that if the print(x) is part of the for loop it will print the elements of the desired list I need, but NOT in a list, which means the math I wrote works as intended, right?

```
list= [1,2,3,4,5]


#loop
x=[]
for i in list:
  x=[i-1]
print(x)

#list comprehension

x=[i-1 for i in list]
print(x)

#confusing part where this print will be the same as the comprehension but not in a list form
 x=[]
for i in list:
  x=[i-1]
  print(x)
```

Comment: I think you meant to do `x += [i-1]` in your loop rather than `x = [i-1]`.  Also please note that naming a list `list` is bad because it shadows the `list` function and will lead to a very confusing bug at some point down the line.

Comment: As a note it's considered best never to name collections the same thing as builtins (`list`, `set`, ..) as it [clobbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clobbering) the builtin in that scope!

Comment: I’ll keep that in mind moving forward, I wanted to be clear by naming it “list” but everyone here knows it I should’ve been aware of thag

Comment: @Oak Practice advice: in business-code you would name the _list_ after its __contents or purpose/role__ within scope. While most educational code applies extremely _abstract naming_, you could start now. Train your __naming skills__,  apply conventions and (best-)practices to make your code easy readable – by e.g. renaming to `numbers` (collection name with plural 's') or `num_list` (mixed name form, see Hungarian-notation) 

Answer (score 1):

First thing, list is a protected keyword. You should be using list_ at least (that's the naming convention if you really need to use list as the name).

The second iterates element by element, and prints each of the elements, what you want is in the loop to set each of the elements one by one, and then print x (not inside the loop).

```
list_= [1,2,3,4,5]

x=[]
for i in list_:
  x.append(i-1)
print(x)
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I completely forgot .append it’s exactly what I was missing. Hopefully these things will stick to memory moving forward.

Comment: @Oak You gave feedback which is helpful. Please turn your thankful words to actions and __upvotie or accept__ ! This is how we reward and say thank-you here

Answer (score 0):

You should append like this:

```
lst= [1,2,3,4,5]

#loop
x=[] 
for i in lst: 
    x.append(i-1)
print(x)
#output: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]

#list comprehension
x=[i-1 for i in lst] 
print(x)
#output: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Comment: you answered twice, remove duplicated answer

Comment: @miquelvir Done!  By the way, your answer (which was posted later) is identical to mine.

Comment: Thank you so much, I completely forgot .append it’s exactly what I was missing. Hopefully these things will stick to memory moving forward.

Comment: perfect! we were writing at the same time it seems; although i explained to the OP the issue with using list as a name... but yes bad luck we both wasted our time

Comment: @pakpe Both your answers are helpful from different perspectives. But honestly, Miquel's answer seems __explaining__ more , which is adequate, __especially to beginners__  While your __code-only__ answer is also adding the __advanced concept__ of _list-comprehension_ (in the same code-block, which makes hard to distinguish this alternative). Might improve 